# Black screen after upgrade to fedora 26

Tags: fedora, login, upgrade, kernel-modules, lightdm

I upgraded my system from Fedora 25 to 26, and after upgrading it rebooted and I got a black screen with a mouse pointer in middle but no GUI to make a login.

There is an error on booting which says

```
Failed to load kernel module
```

What may be the problem, what should I do to make things work?

I tried to boot with changing grub entry and *nomodeset=0* but it comes to the same result. Also, I tried to boot with old kernels of Fedora 25.

**Update**:
I am using [**lightdm**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM) display manager with [lightdm-webkit2-greeter](https://github.com/FallingSnow/lightdm-webkit2-greeter) having material theme.